# I want to run an app on a virtual device on Android Studio but my CPU does not support VT-x / SVM. What can I do?

Tags: android, android-emulator

What can I do to solve this problem?

I have updated Android Studio to the lastest version and couldn't find any useful info in other threads.

Answer (score 1):

you can go for other emulators like genymotion , Andy  or bluestacks they work pretty well with android studios

Comment: Thanks you for helping, I'll try it right now.